# SIM (Systems Integrity monitor) Mariadb on Centos7

Tags: linux, monitoring, centos7, systemd, mariadb

Has anyone got Mariadb monitoring working with SIM on centos7.  My biggest headache is that there is not startup script (or wrapper) in /etc/rc.d/init.d so it is unable to start the service when it detects it is down.

I did not see any documentation on how to make sim work with systemd.  Has anyone done it yet?

Does anyone have an init script that works for mariadb.  I tried the one provided (mysql.server) but get an error on line 286:

```
 mysqld_pid_file_path=$datadir/`@HOSTNAME@`.pid
```

Saying that hostname cannot be found.

Running hostname as a command on shell works just fine though.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 7 uses systemd and rather than a wrapper in /etc/init.d you should be using the `systemctl [stop|start|restart] mariadb` to control MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

As HBrujin said you need to use systemd to start or stop MariaDB in CentOS 7. Remember that you can enable MariaDB to start on boot with "systemctl enable mariadb". Respecting to monitor it with SIM I can't help you, but I can recommend you another monitoring tool if you want.